# can't connect to mtalk.google.com exception in android c2dm

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I did c2dm push service in android.Some times messages are coming from third party application server,but some times it show exception as

caught Could not connect to mtalk.google.com:5228.: (404)

I got response in my server side  as

Content-Length:5id=0:1306769715118610%c11ed14a36225a49

Please tell me why this happens

Comment: Are you sure that this error came from C2DM? mtalk.google.com is the Google Talk server; C2DM is at https://android.clients.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give complete server response with response code. it can be 200, 401 or 503

Also I think that phone is lost connection sometimes and exception tell you that google lost its connection. google need to have permanent connection for work all its services on phone(gmail, c2dm etc.)